# searching a directory for folders

Tags: c++, linux, directory, dirent.h

I'm trying to write a program that gets the path of a folder and prints  directories' names inside it.
This is my code:

```
 if ((dir = opendir (file_path)) != NULL) 
 {
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
    {
       if (stat(ent->d_name, &dir_stat)== 0) 
       {
         if( dir_stat.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
         {
            if(strncmp(ent->d_name, "." ,sizeof(ent->d_name)) != 0
                  && strncmp(ent->d_name, "..",sizeof(ent->d_name)) != 0)
                cout<<"dir : "<< ent->d_name<<endl;
         }

       }
   }
 }
```

Now the problem is that when I give it  "." as file_path it works correctly but when I give it, ./folder as file_path, it does not print anything. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? Does it need to recurse into subdirectories?

Comment: Please format your question properly. Do lines start with `>` in C ?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, but now I just wanna fix this and then do the subdirectory searching.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think chdir() will work. If I change directory and then use "." as file path it will print the subdirectories.

Comment: If you had some error handling/reporting you could've seen what went wrong.

Comment: @MichaelWalz That was me; I code-formatted the originally-quote-formatted code but since I was on mobile I left it at that as a hint for the OP. Ultimately it’s not the most-important thing, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `readdir()` returns the name of the subdirectories, not the path to get to them.

For example if you have a `./folder/sub` then when reading the `./folder` you will get just `sub` as the name. Then, doing a `stat("sub")` will not work, you have to concatenate the directory you are reading:

```
while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
{
   std::string path = dir;
   path += ent->d_name;
   if (stat(path.c_str(), &dir_stat)== 0) 
   {
```

It is usually a good idea to add some `perror()` calls after your system calls:

```
   if (stat(path.c_str(), &dir_stat) < 0) 
       perror(path.c_str());
   else
   {
       ...
```